# Outbreak of a disease within $1000$ people

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

> There are $N=1000$ people.
>
> At day $d=0$ we have $Z=1$ unkown person that is infected with a disease. Every night all of the $N$ people are sharing in groups of $2$ a room together.
>
> At day $d=1$ we have $Z=2$ persons that are infected. At the next night every person shares a room with a new random person.
>
> So at day $d=2$ we have $Z=4$ people who are infected. We repeat this.
>
> What is the distribution of $Z$? What is the expected value of $Z$ in relation to $d$? Assuming nobody gets treated well, when will everybody be infected?
>
> How do I solve this? I have troubles to find a distribution. Is $Z$ binomial distributed?

I guess $E(Z)$ is easy when knowing the distribution.

Edit: Since the restriction that nobody shares the room twice with someone made it too complicated, I removed it. If anyone still know how to do this in that case, please feel free to solve it with the restriction.

Comment: Is this an exercise or a question of your own? Do you need to calculate the distribution of $Z$ or is the expectation enough?

Comment: @Dominik I've read something similar somewhere but I made it a question of my own. Both would be good. But I thought if the distribution is known, then it's easy to calculate. So I assume the distribution is complicated?

Comment: I assume that it is indeed very complicated. Perhaps it is possible to get the expectation using conditional expectations, but I don't have a solution myself.

Comment: @Dominik So I assume it's complicated because of $N=1000$? I don't really bother if someone solves it for a lower number like $N=100$ or even $N=50$ or $N=25$. But I thought there might be a better way to solve this besides writing out all the possible events.

Comment: No, it is complicated because of the restriction that no pair that was together previously will be together again.

Comment: @Dominik Ok I removed the restriction. Is it now hypergeometrical distributed? 
We never really solved "application" exercise where we had to find a distribution from a text. So I'm not really good at seeing what kind of distribution is underlying.

Comment: Unfortunately, this Problem is still too complicated to solve with a simple recursion and conditional expectations.I thought it was possible, but the resulting recursion is nonlinear.

Comment: @Dominik Ok still thank you for your time!